# Were radio frequency radiation levels raised to accommodate mobile phones?

Tags: radiation, mobile-phones

When I was at university (in Australia) a lecturer mentioned that the Australian standard for radio frequency radiation levels were deliberately raised to accommodate mobile phone technology. So that the previous recommended level of dosage was raised so that mobile phones could be sold.

Is this true and was this done in countries other than Australia?

I have found [this page](http://www.geomantica.com/geom16.htm) on the internet which seems to partially confirm his claim:

> "Why do we need a new standard when
>   technology is operating perfectly well
>   at the present lower levels?" asks EMR
>   News. It seems that "Last year the
>   committee that devised the standards
>   was told that the higher radiation
>   levels were needed to accommodate new
>   mobile phone technology. That begs the
>   important question: has the
>   standards-setting process been driven
>   by scientific research or by economic
>   motives?"
>
> A copy of the standard and supporting
>   documents is available from ARPANSA's
>   website at
>   [www.arpansa.gov.au/rf_standard.htm](http://www.arpansa.gov.au/rf_standard.htm)
>
> Source: EMR News June 2002.

Comment: That specific standard was most recently revised in 1998, and prior to that was written in 1990, see [here](http://infostore.saiglobal.com/store2/Details.aspx?ProductID=366231). Unfortunately those standards are pretty expensive to buy and have a look at, so I can't tell you the differences, nor do I know whether there was some applicable standard prior to 1990.

Comment: It’s news to me that there is even such a thing as regulated radio frequency radiation levels (as opposed to other forms of radiation which are ionising). Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @Konrad - The link in the quote above redirects to the page where the current standard is listed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ICNIRP](http://www.icnirp.de/) is the **International Commission on Non-Ionizing Radiation Protection**.

[image: ICNIRP][<sub>Image Source</sub>](http://www.conformity.com/artman/publish/printer_210.shtml)

In **1998** the

> [Guidelines for Limiting Exposure to
>   Time-Varying Electric, Magnetic, and
>   Electromagnetic Fields (up to 300 GHz)](http://www.icnirp.de/documents/emfgdl.pdf)

were published (they include radiation from mobile phones).

They form the basis of [WHO](http://www.who.int/peh-emf/en/) and [ITU](http://www.itu.int/net/home/index.aspx) recommendations to governments [all around the world](http://www.who.int/peh-emf/standards/en/).

> **These guidelines will be periodically
>   revised and updated** as advances are
>   made in identifying the adverse health
>   effects of time-varying electric,
>   magnetic, and electromagnetic fields.

(e.g. [2009 Statement on EMF Guidlines](http://www.icnirp.de/documents/StatementEMF.pdf))

You can look up the standards in your country using the

**[EMF World Wide Standards Database](http://www.who.int/docstore/peh-emf/EMFStandards/who-0102/Worldmap5.htm)**

---

**EDIT:**

According to [this study](http://www.arpansa.gov.au/RadiationProtection/BaseStationSurvey/limits.cfm) the exposure limits for the relevant moblie phone frequencies of the [ARPANSA standard](http://www.arpansa.gov.au/Publications/codes/rps3.cfm) (current standard in Australia) are

> equivalent to those of the 1998
>   Guidelines published by the
>   ICNIRP.